# Separate buffer for road lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, buffer

I want to a buffer around road (dwg file) in Arcgis. I am merging road lines but there are separate buffers for every line of road.

[image]

Comment: Welcome and don't apologize for your English. However, your question is not very clear, I think you need to add more information.

Comment: Thanks..I use Arcgis 10.1. I work on a dwg file in Arcmap. Firstly, I selection polyline feature in Add data. I selected road in selection by attribute and saved  shape file .Then, I merged all of road lines and I  want to create a buffer around road but It was created double buffer around roads two lines.Why?

Comment: Can you please add a picture of what you want the output to look like in the example on the right (with the two lines)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what desktop software you are using, however here are the general steps below:

1. Convert dwg line layer to shapefile
2. Use dissolve geoprocessing tool to create a one feature polyline layer
3. Buffer dissolved layer from step two above

This will produce a seamless polygon layer.

Comment: I use Arcgis 10.1. I work on a dwg file in Arcmap. Firstly, I selection polyline feature in Add data. I selected road in selection by attribute and saved  shape file .Then, I merged all of road lines and I  want to create a buffer around road but It was created double buffer around roads two lines.Why? I tried your steps...It's no use. :(

Comment: The buffer honors each part of the multipart geometry. Perhaps you are wanting the feature envelope?  It is the minimum bounding box.https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm%3FTopicName%3Dfeature_envelope_to_polygon_(data_management)&ved=0ahUKEwjO6fHlhK3LAhWH8j4KHWenBAIQFgggMAI&usg=AFQjCNHOf8xz3I0TkzNeIZSunrAyINHowA&sig2=VLAYipFNc1S_B6GK2r6Brg